# SwipeRefreshLayout in RelativeLayout - pass clicks to previous sibling

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.message));
```

In strings.xml

```
<string name="message"><![CDATA[Visit <a href="http://example.com">this site</a>]]></string>
```

Clicking to url in TextView does no work, because all the touches are intercepted by SwipeRefreshLayout.

How could I make SwipeRefreshLayout transparent for cliks in TextView's url, but at the same time let swipes work?

Comment: You can use this property: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

Comment: Doesn't help. Pay attention to layout hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only asing to TextView a ID, then, asing onClick event only to your TextView. This event you can call in your activity or fragment.

[update]

In the XML, try with this properties and some margin between your Textview and your swipelayout

```
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:marginBottom="10dp"
```

Comment: Aaa Ok, in this case your textview need some properties like this:

        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"

Try it

Comment: No problem with link. I see the link, and as only I drop out SwipeRefreshLayout the link become clickable. But with SwipeRefreshLayout it just visible, but no clickable. I believe it's because SwipeRefreshLayout does intercept all the touches.